# How to set viewbag value for all actions in ASP.NET MCV controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a dynamic menu. I have created a base controller (`class PortalController : Controller`) i have added some virtual methods to this class. One of these methods is to generate html for the sites menu. This allows me to write it once and override it if i need to. The problem is it is bad practice to directly call methods from the view.

I want to be able to use this method to create a viewbag string that contains the html for the main menu. The problem i have here is that all methods need to call this generateMenu() method before returning the view. Its a solution, but i dont like it. Is there a cleaner way to do this at the object level. By default any object that inherits "PortalController" will automatically have the menu string in a viewbag variable. How can i do this?

So far i have written this. what i would really like is almost the equivalent of a constructor. The menu will be generated when the object is constructed. Using the method below is only going to render the menu when the view is called. I need the ability for multiple actions in a controller to have different items in the menu.

```
protected override ViewResult View(IView view, object model)
{
    ViewBag.Menu = this.GenerateMenu();
    return base.View(view, model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can in all Views from PortalController generate this menu using `Html.Partial` and pass some object as model for this view (if it needs)

```
@model Foo

@Html.Partial("menu", Foo)

/* rest of the page */
<form>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in obligation to generate menu html in the controller?
I think it is a bad parctice.
You can start with the basic menu and manipulate it using css.
The menu must be in the layout page, or in a partial view which will be called in other concerned views.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                 </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
 </div>
```

you display menu dymanically using jquery css display or hide with roles in controller action.
You get menus to display  using a call ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically building the menu item (from a db etc), you may create an action method which can be called from your layout file.

```
public ActionResult RenderMenu()
{
  // Build the data needed to render the menu. Pass to the view

    var menu = new List<MenuItem>
    {
        new MenuItem(){
            Text = "Home",
            Childs = new List<MenuItem>
            {
                new MenuItem {Text = "About"}
            }
        }
    };
  return PartialView(menuItems);
}
```

Assuming you have a MenuItem class like this

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Text { set; get; }
    public string TargetUrl { set; get; }
    public List<MenuItem> Childs { set; get; }
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.Childs=new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}
```

and in your view, you will use this to render your menu item however you want.

To include this menu in all pages, you can simply call the Html.Action method in the Layout

```
@Html.Action("RenderMenu","ControllerName")
```

Or if you want to set something to viewbag in for all your requests, you can create an action filter to do that.

```
public class LoadMenu : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var vb = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag; 
        vb.Menu = "Some string you want";
    }
}
```

and register this as a global filter in Global.asax.cs's `Application_Start` event.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LoadMenu());
```